# Minimum change that cannot be created

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

The following code finds the minimum change that *cannot* be created from a list of coins.

For example, the minimum change that cannot be created from `[1,2,5]` is 4.

This works for the following array `[5,7,1,1,2,3,22]` which is 20.

However, I cannot figure out how to account for the array `[1,1,1,1,1]`.

The minimum change I cannot create is 6.

How can I account for the array of ones? Thank you.

```
function nonConstructibleChange(coins) {
      
  coins.sort( (a,b) => a - b);
    
  let currentChangeCreated = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {

    if (coins[i] > currentChangeCreated + 1) {
      return currentChangeCreated + 1;
    }

    currentChangeCreated += coins[i];

  }
        
  return currentChangeCreated;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate over all the coins and haven't yet found the result, then the minimum change you *cannot* create must be the total of all the coins + 1.

Change the final return statement to:

```
return currentChangeCreated + 1
```

By the way, your successful test cases all complete and return before exhausting the list of coins, hence that final return statement is not executed in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

As for [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], you can create any change between 1 and 5, so 6 it's just the closest you can't create after 5.

Comment: yes they know that, but their code, does not produce this desired output (6) - their question is: how to change the code, that those type of arrays (arrays that completely iterate in the for loop) are accounted for. - because as it stands now, passing the array [1,1,1,1,1] does not return 6